# Nested if not working in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, nested-if

I have this table in oracle 11g

```
 count  day
  0     MONDAY
  0     TUESDAY
  1     WEDNESDAY
  1     THURSDAY
```

and then I am doing a for :

```
 loop
 IF (J.DAY='MONDAY' AND J.COUNT=0) THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MONDAY IN');
    IF (J.DAY='TUESDAY' AND J.COUNT=0) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TUESDAY IN');  
    END IF;
  END IF;
  end loop
```

But just shows MONDAY IN, so is not taking the second condition, maybe I am writing bad the code.

Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it :D

```
 loop
  IF (J.DAY='MONDAY' AND J.COUNT=0) THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MONDAY IN');
   ELSIF (J.DAY='TUESDAY' AND J.COUNT=0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TUESDAY IN');  
   END IF;
  END IF;
 end loop
```

Comment: I see 2 `END IF`s here and you use just one `IF - ELSE` block.
Here is some nice info about if-else statements - [IF-THEN-ELSE techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php)